# Resetting root password in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, boot, password, root, grub

Having a bit of an problem resetting my root password on a dedicated server with 1&1, running CentOS7.

Able to access GRUB through terminal and can bring up the below, however this looks different to many examples out there.

```
setparams 'CentOS Linux, with Linux 3.10.0-327.28.2.el7.x86_64'

load_video
set gfxpayload=keep                                                    
insmod gzio                                                            
insmod part_msdos                                                      
insmod diskfilter mdraid09                                             
insmod ext2                                                            
set root='hd0,msdos1'   

linux16 /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-327.28.2.el7.x86_64 rd.driver.pre=raid1,ahci,dm_mod root=/dev/md1 domdadm dolvm rd.lvm.vg=vg00 rd.lvm.lv=vg00/usr ro console=ttyS0,57600 console=tty0 net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0
initrd16 /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-327.28.2.el7.x86_64.img
```

I have tried to change the ro line to rw and add init=/sysroot/bin/sh but this hasn't helped.

When going through the loading process I get the error

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Switch Root.
See 'systemctl status initrd-switch-root.service' for details.
```

Comment: Is this really duplicate as Tom wrote that he tried the old init=/bin/sh trick but it did not work with systemd?
BTW, Tom, what is "/sysroot/"? Does it really belong there? Did you try init=/bin/sh?

Answer (score 2):

Try "systemd.unit=rescue.target" to the "linux16" line as described in https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#Boot_Kernel_Command_Line

Comment: On my system (RHEL 7.6 FWIW), this recipe boots to rescue mode, which requires the root password and thus defeats the purpose. I had success with dr01's recipe using rd.break on the kernel config line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to reset the root password in CentOS 7 and RHEL 7:

1. Power up the system and, on the GRUB 2 boot screen, press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit the current entry.
2. Edit the line with `linux16`, removing the `rhgb` and `quiet` parameters and adding `rd.break` at the end.
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>; the system will boot on the initramfs `switch_root` prompt.
4. Remount the filesystem as writable: `mount -o remount,rw /sysroot`
5. Change the filesystem root: `chroot /sysroot`
6. Modify the root password: `passwd root`
7. Force SELinux to relabel context on next boot: `touch /.autorelabel`
8. Remount the filesystem as readonly: `mount -o remount,ro /sysroot`
9. Exit the chroot environment: `exit`
10. Resume system boot: `exit`

Source: [a guide](https://issuu.com/daniele.raffo/docs/linux-guide-4ed) that I wrote some time ago.

Comment: Hi. I do not have "rhgb" and "quiet" paramaters as per my quoted code.

Comment: Since it's a 1&1 dedicated server, have you tried https://help.1and1.com/servers-c37684/dedicated-server-linux-c37687/administration-c37694/reset-your-lostforgotten-root-password-a686007.html ?